# Flutter hide keyboard when icon keyboard is shown

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

When I click the emoji icon, the emoji keyboard is shown. But then I click on the textfield without closing the emoji keyboard, the text keyboard is displayed on the bottom of the emoji keyboard like the picture above:

[image]

What I want is whenever the emoji keyboard is shown, then the text keyboard is hidden. And when the text keyboard is shown, then the emoji keyboard is hidden.

Here is my code :

```
bool emojiShowing = false;

  _onEmojiSelected(Emoji emoji) {
    inputTextController
      ..text += emoji.emoji
      ..selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
          TextPosition(offset: inputTextController.text.length));
  }

  _onBackspacePressed() {
    inputTextController
      ..text = inputTextController.text.characters.skipLast(1).toString()
      ..selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
          TextPosition(offset: inputTextController.text.length));
  }
   
   final _focusNode = FocusNode();
   final _textFieldKey = UniqueKey();
```

The textfield controller:

```
TextEditingController inputTextController = new TextEditingController();
```

The icon button code:

```
                 IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            emojiShowing = !emojiShowing;
                            if (emojiShowing) {
                              _focusNode.unfocus();
                            }
                            else {
                              FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode);
                            }
                          });
                        },
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.tag_faces,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
```

And the emoji code:

```
      Offstage(
          offstage: !emojiShowing,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 250,
            child: EmojiPicker(
                onEmojiSelected: (Category category, Emoji emoji) {
                  _onEmojiSelected(emoji);
                },
                onBackspacePressed: _onBackspacePressed,
                config: Config(
                    columns: 7,
                    // Issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28894
                    emojiSizeMax: 32 * (Platform.isIOS ? 1.30 : 1.0),
                    verticalSpacing: 0,
                    horizontalSpacing: 0,
                    initCategory: Category.SMILEYS,
                    bgColor: Colors.white,
                    indicatorColor: Colors.blue,
                    iconColor: Colors.grey,
                    iconColorSelected: Colors.blue,
                    progressIndicatorColor: Colors.blue,
                    backspaceColor: Colors.blue,
                    skinToneDialogBgColor: Colors.white,
                    skinToneIndicatorColor: Colors.grey,
                    enableSkinTones: true,
                    showRecentsTab: true,
                    recentsLimit: 28,
                    noRecentsText: 'No Recents',
                    noRecentsStyle: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black26),
                    tabIndicatorAnimDuration: kTabScrollDuration,
                    categoryIcons: const CategoryIcons(),
                    buttonMode: ButtonMode.MATERIAL)),
          ),
        ),
```

Added `key: _textFieldKey,` to the TextField too.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use
`final _focusNode = FocusNode();`

set the focus node to the `Textfield` widget `focusNode: _focusNode,` and you can use `_focusNode.unfocus()` to loose focus when the EmojiPicker is open and `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode);` to regain focus to the `TextInput`

Comment: where should i put the `_focusNode.unfocus()` and the `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode);` ?

Comment: I would put it inside the

`setState(() {emojiShowing = !emojiShowing;});`

of `IconButton` if `emojiShowing` is `true`

Comment: Is this right? 

`onPressed: () {
setState(() {
emojiShowing = !emojiShowing;
_focusNode.unfocus();
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode);
});
},`

Comment: setState(() {
      emojiShowing = !emojiShowing;
      if (emojiShowing) {
        _focusNode.unfocus();
      } else {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode);
      }
    });

Comment: works well when I open the text keyboard first then click the emoji keyboard. but not when the emoji keyboard is already opened then i click the textfield

Comment: In this case, if I understand you correctly, you should use the `onTap` prop of TextInput to hide emoji picker when you tap on the textfield. Something like this `onTap: () { setState(() { emojiShowing = false; }; }`

Comment: this still doesn't work

Comment: Can you explain clearly what doesn't work? It'll help a lot

Comment: when I open the emoji keyboard after that i click on text field, the text keyboard and the emoji keyboard is displayed like the picture in my question.

Comment: Ok, I think what's missing now is the `key` prop for TextField widget. You can create a variable like this `final _textFieldKey = UniqueKey();` and set `key: _textFieldKey` to TextField. ps: don't create this variable inside the `build` method of your widget. It should be outside / before it

Comment: i did as you said but still didn't work

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't remove the `onTap` from the Textfield right? Also can you update your question and add the code as it is? It'll help to better understand what's going wrong. You could add only the part that's related to this issue

Comment: I've removed it but still didn't work, also, I've updated my questions please have a look